# SciPy step response plot seems to break for some values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm using SciPy instead of MATLAB in a control systems class to plot the step responses of LTI systems. It's worked great so far, but I've run into an issue with a very specific system. With this code:

```py
from numpy import min
from scipy import linspace
from scipy.signal import lti, step
from matplotlib import pyplot as p

# Create an LTI transfer function from coefficients
tf = lti([64], [1, 16, 64])
# Step response (redo it to get better resolution)
t, s = step(tf)
t, s = step(tf, T = linspace(min(t), t[-1], 200))
# Plotting stuff
p.plot(t, s)
p.xlabel('Time / s')
p.ylabel('Displacement / m')
p.show()
```

The code as-is displays a flat line. If I modify the final coefficient of the denominator to `64.00000001` (i.e., `tf = lti([64], [1, 16, 64.0000001])`) then it works as it should, showing an underdamped step response. Setting the coefficient to `63.9999999` also works. Changing all the coefficients to have explicit decimal places (i.e.,  `tf = lti([64.0], [1.0, 16.0, 64.0])`) doesn't affect anything, so I guess it's not a case of integer division messing things up.

Is this a bug in SciPy, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'instead of', you are using scipy for computation and maplotlib for plotting, exactly as they are designed to be used.

Comment: Are you sure that that set of parameters is non-singular?  And are you having any issues with matplotlib, or just using it?

Comment: @tcaswell I'm using Python libraries instead of using MATLAB. I wasn't aware the parameters had to be non-singular, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a limitation of the implementation of the `step` function.  It uses a matrix exponential to find the step response, and it doesn't handle repeated poles well. (Your system has a repeated pole at -8.)

Instead of using `step`, you can use the function [scipy.signal.step2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.step2.html#scipy.signal.step2)

```
In [253]: from scipy.signal import lti, step2

In [254]: sys = lti([64], [1, 16, 64])

In [255]: t, y = step2(sys)

In [256]: plot(t, y)
Out[256]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x5ec6b90>]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea there'd be a problem with repeated poles. In general, can `step2` replace `step`?

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster: Yes, you can use `step2` to replace `step` in general.

Comment: @pv.: Sure, but `step` should really be improved.  Further comments could be made here: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/577